# Is there any way to sort "Faces" alphabetically in the new Photos App for OSX?

Tags: photos.app

In the new Photos app, you can still use face detection (or manual face tagging) to label faces, so you can easily pull up all pictures with a certain person in them, etc.

Faces now lives in the "Albums" tab, where there's essentially a "faces" folder.  But when you open it...
[image]
...there seem to be two categories:

1. A few "featured" faces on top, which are larger (I'm not sure if these are "most recent" or "most photos"
2. All the other (smaller) faces.

**How can I sort the full list of (smaller) faces in some way that lets me find a specific one.  Like, alphabetically, say?**

I have ~300 tagged faces, so browsing by face is simply not efficient when I'm looking for a specific person.

Comment: It doesn't look like this is a feature that is currently possible, what you could do though, is submit a feature request to Apple, or even a bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's now a sort by name feature! In Photos version 1.2, you can go to the Faces view and then do View > Sort > Keep Sorted By Name. Ridiculously, this is apparently turned off by default if you upgraded from a previous version.

Anyway, this will make my use of Photos way way easier. (I have 1400+ faces.)

Comment: It appears this feature has been disabled since version 1.2. In Photos version 3.0 the View > Sort > Keep Sorted By Name is disabled (greyed out) and I cannot find any way to re-sort the People/faces other than manually dragging them around!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can sort faces manually by dragging them including top faces

Comment: He wants them to be automatically sorted alphabetically, not manually sorted via drag and drop.

Comment: I saw but actually it's not possible (I'm studying photos sort option from days!) and actually is the only way...reply just "no" to his question won't sounds nice! He seems ignore the possibility to drag faces so I tell it!

Comment: Yeah, I really was looking for a way to sort them in some predictable (but not manual) way, BUT this is a helpful hack if that's truly not possible, so +1 for improving my current situation!